# Why can't I connect remotely to MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database set up on a server, I've created a user and granted all privileges to that user from any address but I can't connect remotely to the database via any software I use.

I've checked the port is correct and skip-networking is off and bind-address is not set to local only. What else should I check?

Comment: Can you `telnet` to the server on port 3306?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a user like root@'%', you should be able to connect. You should change this to root@'xx.xx.xx.%' instead of root@'%' as you do not want remote access that wide open.

You may need to check your firewall settings.

Try this

```
service iptables stop
```

then try connecting again

Comment: Don't just leave iptables stopped.  Write an iptables rule for the mysql traffic..

Answer (score 2):

Things to check:

- Is MySQL running?
- Did you run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` to ensure your grants updated?
- Can the *server* access the outside world?
- Does a local TCP connection work? `mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 -uroot -p`
- Is inbound port reachable via `nmap` or `telnet`?

Other than that, you will have to provide more information: The exact error you get when you try to access remotely from your MySQL client.

Answer (score 1):

Your bind-address in my.cnf will probably be 127.0.0.1. This way it won't allow external access.
Change this to your internet IP will solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Check to ensure Windows Firewall is not blocking the port 3306.

Steps I took on my Windows 10 server:

1. Start > "Allow an app through Windows Firewall"
2. Find "MySQLxx"
3. Press "Change Settings"
4. Make sure "Private" and "Public" are both checked